# Can Molisch test be used to separate monosaccharides from polysaccharides?

Tags: biochemistry, carbohydrates

Do the results of Molisch test on monosaccharides have any differences with when it's done to disaccharides or polysaccharides?

Answer (score 1):

No. Mono and poly saccharides both give a positive test.